# Consistent floating point arithmetic in fortran with different compilers on different computers?

Tags: math, floating-point

How can I get the same results with floating-point arithmetic using different compilers and possibly also different computers?

This is p.f90

```
program fl
implicit none
real(kind=8) :: a

a=9d0/10d0
write(*,*) a

end program
```

With gfortran -o p p.f90 I get 0.90000000000000002

With ifort -g -o p p.f90 I get 0.900000000000000

Is there a way to achieve consistency?
The small things propagate and become larger.

Best regards
Alessandro

Answer (score 8):

We'll turn to floating-point arithmetic below, but let me deal first with a misconception you have.  Your use of *list-directed formatting* in the write statement means that the format chosen by the compiler to write out a variable is, well, the compiler's choice; it's not mandated by the language standard.  Your use of the second `*` in `write(*,*)` tells the compiler to write out the value of a variable as it wishes.  So what you have is not evidence that there is something wrong with the arithmetic, but that there are differences between `gfortran` and `ifort`.  If I modify your write statement to

```
write(*,'(f21.18)') a
```

then my Intel Fortran program writes

```
0.900000000000000022
```

to the console.

SO is littered with questions arising from unfamiliarity with the details of floating-point arithmetic so I'm not going to write a treatise, just a few observations relevant to your question.

IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point numbers (which is probably what you get with the declaration `real(kind=8)`) only provide approximately 16 decimal digits of useful information.  Actually, since they're binary and there is no easy correspondence between the number of digits in one base and in another, it's actually 15.95 decimal digits and many users round this down and never look at anything after the 15th significant figure in a floating-point number's decimal representation.  So both `ifort` and `gfortran` are misleading you with their trailing `2`s.

IEEE-754 defines not only the formats for f-p numbers, but also some rules for rounding and for arithmetic operations.  A carefully-written program which uses only those arithmetic operations (I think square root is also specified) and which takes care about rounding modes and rounding operations should produce the same results on two different processors.  Of course, not many useful numerical programs confine themselves to the basic arithmetic operations.

Since the 2003 standard Fortran has included an intrinsic module called `ieee_arithmetic` which gives the programmer direct access to the underlying IEEE-754 capabilities of the hardware on which it is running -- but note that it does not require that the hardware have any such capabilities.  Using `ieee_arithmetic` and another intrinsic module called `ieee_exceptions` you should, if your hardware provides the necessary support, be able to write programs which compile under both `gfortran` and `ifort` and which produce, when executed, the same results to the last bit of every f-p number.

You'll also need to familiarise yourself with the optimisation options and numerical arithmetic options of the compiler(s) you're using.  Most compilers have an option whose meaning is `sacrifice IEEE compliance for speed` (for `ifort` I think it's `fp-model`).  In general adherence to IEEE-754 for operations will slow your programs.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try to find a real example of compiler-dependent behaviour as short as above. With loops it is quite easy to achieve, if the compiler changes the order. Also I am interested whether commutativity is always respected or not.

Comment: @HighPerfomanceMark Hello, when saying that IEEE-754 64 bit f-p numbers provide 15.95 decimal digits, do you mean that there is a 5% chance that the 16th digit is just rubbish? This is an old question but I just came across it. Thanks

Comment: No, that's not what I mean at all.  Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation, in fact have a look at that whole article.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot.**

See under *Systems Aspects* in [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

As Ali: You cannot.

It is a well known problem of FORTRAN compilers that results cannot be compared with different compilers and architectures.
The main reason that it is impossible has to do with a design decision of the FORTRAN
community: The computer may change the execution order and use internal computer
specialities to optimize speed.
As floating-point arithmetic is NOT distributive [ x(y+z) != xy + xz ] and the result DOES
depend on the execution order

e.g.

1E308 (MAX) + (1E308  - 2E308) ~= 0E308

(1E308 (MAX) + 1E308)  - 2E308  == INFINITY

you are stuck. Some compilers use e.g. the Fused multiply-add for calculating polynominals which give different results than the "normal" and this is quite allowed.

You are stuck. Sorry.