# double precision on IBM xlf compiler

Tags: fortran, precision

I'm trying to port a program from Red Hat Linux to IBM AIX, but the precision on the IBM system seems different to the Red Hat system. Does anyone know why this is happing? Here is an example:

```
program main
implicit none
real(8) a
a=0.2D0
print *,a
end program
```

On Red Hat I get output:

```
0.200000000000000
```

On AIX I get output:

```
0.200000000000000011
```

The version of the system I'm using:

IBM XL Fortran for AIX, V13.1 (5724-X15)
Version: 13.01.0000.0005

and

Linux 2.6.18-8.el5 x86_64

ifort Version 10.0

Comment: See the first paragraph of my answer to this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135262/consistent-floating-point-arithmetic-in-fortran-with-different-compilers-on-diff/13136763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably just a difference in the default number of digits printed. `0.2` cannot be accurately represented as a binary floating point number, so you are always going to have some garbage in the least significant digits. The default number of digits printed for a float with `ifort` is simply set to be low enough that you don't see it in this case. The actual calculation (most likely) has the same precision. Try this with both compilers:

```
print '(f24.20)',0.2d0
```

This will show you that `ifort` also has the ones at the end. On my computer, it prints `0.20000000000000001110`.

Answer (score 1):

The * in the print statement means list directed formatting.  For real constants, "reasonable **processor-dependent** values" (F2008 10.10.4 p6) for the number of digits are used.  You've changed Fortran processors and those processors have simply chosen a different number of digits as being reasonable.

If you want to explicitly control the output format, then use an explicit output format that specifies the field width, the number of decimal digits and (possibly) the number of exponent characters.  This removes processor-dependency.

The in-memory precision of the variable is probably the same for both processors (assuming that KIND(1.0D0) == 8 and that KIND of 8 means IEEE double precision), noting that 0.2 is not exactly representable in that floating point representation.